# How to pass data from Joomla sub controller to view?

Tags: php, joomla, scope, variable-assignment

I have seen many examples to pass data from a Joomla controller to views (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325230/how-does-joomla-model-view-controller-mvc-work)). But I need to pass a Joomla sub controller to a specific view file (view.html.php). I searched about it for a whole day and did not found a solution. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: why can't you use the subcontroller to render the view? subcontroller should have all of its parents behavior

Comment: No machan if i just need to render the view i could do it with $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('path to my view'));. but I could not find a way to pass some data with it and access them in the view

Comment: when you say sub-controller your saying something that Extends JController right?

Comment: check here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/O_T0tqbiU4Q if you haven't already that is

Comment: Yes it its grand parent is the Jcontroller I dose not help

Comment: I cannot understand what does that means to pass even controller to view. Anв what is sub-controller? There is not anything like that in joomla. What Joomla version are you using? It is quite different in 2.5 and 3.0

Comment: What do you mean by there is noting like that(subcontrollr). Refer joomla docs.http://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview#Subcontrollers.
BTW.
I'm using joomla 2.5

Comment: @SergeyRomanov usually by subcontroller people mean the individual controllers in the controllers folder as opposed to the controller in the extension root folder.

Comment: I manage to transfer the data with a session. But I'm not satisfied with that solution. There go to be a better way!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joomla MVC is very loose and you can implement this behaviour in several ways.
I think this is the most standard sequence to implement MVC in Joomla:

1. The controller reads the input and sets the relevant parameters in a session variable
2. The controller redirects to the view
3. The view loads the model
4. The model reads the params from the session.

But you could handle the params in 3. and pass them on to the model; this really is a matter of style/taste.  Since Joomla allows you to invoke your model from the view with $this->get('Data') for example, there is no room for passing params; you can  however choose to invoke $model->getData2($param1,$param2).

The basic calls are:

```
JApplication::getUserStateFromRequest()
```

which in a single call reads the input and falls back on the previously saved session data;

**setUserState** to persist this info in the session and 
**getUserState** to be used in the model to retrieve the data.

You can however simply redirect passing the params in the url; then use the view.html.php to parse the input and set the internal state of the model before calling methods ($model->setState), or avoid redirect entirely and load the models and view from the controller (which seems a more standard and easy approach to MVC, but is seldom seen in Joomla).

**Directly invoking the view from the controller**

```
    $vName      = 'yourview';
    $vFormat    = 'html'; // raw

    if ($view = $this->getView($vName, $vFormat)) {
        $model = $this->getModel($vName);
        $model->setState('filter.type', $type);
        $view->setModel($model, true);

        // Push document object into the view.
        $view->assignRef('document', $document);

        $view->display();
    }
```

Comment: I am communicating with models in  $model->getData2($param1,$param2) way. My question was to communicate view and controller. I think there should be a way to do this without sessions.

Comment: well you can setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=...&param1=something&param2=somethingelse; or you can instantiate the view manually from the controller and invoke its render() method.

Comment: Yes these are good. Thanks. But I still wish if there is a function like all other frameworks.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I put in a sample of how to invoke the view directly from the controller